# Multipart with Spring Boot Rest Service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a REST-Service defined with as follow

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}/profileimage/{language}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String uploadProfileImage(@PathVariable String userId, @RequestParam MultipartFile file, @PathVariable String language) throws IOException { ...}
```

and defined a multipart filter

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean multipartFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegBean.setFilter(new MultipartFilter());
    List<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<String>();
    urlPatterns.add("/*");
    filterRegBean.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
    return filterRegBean;
}
```

as well as a multipartConfigElement

```
@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement(){
    MultipartConfigElement config = new MultipartConfigElement("");
    return config;
}
```

But I still get the following Exception when I send a multipart message to the REST service:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/dev] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?]

The service is protected by spring security (as a side information) and Spring Boot logs the following on startup

> Added existing Filter initializer bean 'multipartFilter'; order=2147483647, resource=class path resource [com/fl/wir/config/MvcConfigurations.class]
>
> Mapping filter: 'multipartFilter' to urls: [/*]
>
> MultipartAutoConfiguration
>         - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver,javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement (OnClassCondition)
>         - matched (OnPropertyCondition)
>
> DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletConfiguration#multipartResolver
>         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: multipartResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [multipartResolver] (OnBeanCondition)

Any idea why I still get the exception? 
(using Spring-Boot 1.2.3.RELEASE)

Comment: Don't specify those just add the [appropriate properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration) to the `application.properties`. Also file upload and PUT won't work, only for POST.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making it way to complex, to enable file uploading simply configure it correctly using [properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration) in the `application.properties`.

```
multipart.enabled=true
```

And make sure you have `spring-webmvc` on your class path (judging from the annotations used you already have).

However there is one other thing and that is that file upload will [only work for POST](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardServletMultipartResolver.java#L67) requests not any other, so PUT will not work.

Comment: main issue was that I used PUT. rest was working out of the box but error message was not really helping me to find that out.

Comment: to support PUT 

http://i-proving.com/2015/05/14/submitting-a-multipart-request-multipartform-data-using-put-and-spring-boot/

Comment: That would be `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true` for Spring Boot 2.